# big for loop hangs javascript engine

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, firefox, for-loop

recently when I was tackling a algorithm problem, I found a plain big for loop like this

```
var x = 1000000000000;
for (var i = 0; i <= x; i++) {}
```

can hang javascript engine (tested on node.js, Chrome, and Firefox javascript console).

Actually it is running, but very slow. I tried several value of x, and there is noticeable delay when x = 1000000.

Is this performance normal to a interpret language?

Comment: Runs fine for me in Node. No hanging.

Comment: When looping through such a big number of iterations, the system will definitely hang, regardless of what language you are using. However, most interpreter will not even try to run your loop since `i` is never used after the loop, and the loop does nothing.

Comment: What did you expect to happen? The browser does not do pre-emptive multi-tasking. The engine is not "hanging", it's "thinking".

Comment: Thanks you guys, now I have sense about loop -- it is really a time-consuming task for any language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use some form of [loop unrolling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_unrolling),  break up the loop into chunks, e.g. using [Duffs device](http://home.earthlink.net/~kendrasg/info/js_opt/jsOptMain.html#duffsdevice), or use a mechanism described [here](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/01/13/speed-up-your-javascript-part-1/).

The behavior is not confined to interpreted languages. The loop will always last long to very long. Try for example `for (long n = 1000000000000; n >= 0; n-=1) {}` in c#.

Finally, within a (modern) browser using [web workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/Performance/Using_web_workers) may be viable. Here's [an example](http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/x7mogd2g/) I created for another SO-question.

Comment: You copied my link ;)

Answer (score 2):

This will be slow in any language. It's just especially noticeable in this case since it's blocking your UI. JavaScript engines execute a single threaded event loop. You can always [use web workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Performance/Using_web_workers) to execute slow processing tasks in the background.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't be a problem with real-world cases, I tested on MacBook Pro laptop:

- 1,000,000 loop iterations
- each iteration invokes a (simple) function
- takes 2-3ms on first few rounds (cold compiler)
- takes ~0.5ms after that (compiler optimizes hot code)

If you need to iterate over super-hyper-mega values, I'd split it up into smaller junks and use `setTimeout` or `requestAnimationFrame` to spread the workload over different frames and not cause any framedrops (frame has ~16ms to do all the work).

```js
console.clear();

// options
const start = true;
const useFastTick = false; // 3ms per tick vs e.g 1s
const interval = 1; // 1: once/sec, 2: twice/sec, etc
const iterations = 1000000;

function emptyFn() {}

function argsFn(obj) {}

function emptyFns() {
  for (let i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
    if (i !== undefined && i !== null) emptyFn();
  }
}

function argsFns() {
  for (let i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
    argsFn({a: 'hey', b: i, c: false});
  }
}


function tick() {
  const all0 = performance.now();

  const empty0 = performance.now();
  emptyFns();
  const empty1 = performance.now();

  const args0 = performance.now();
  argsFns();
  const args1 = performance.now();

  const all1 = performance.now();

  const all = (all1 - all0).toFixed(3);
  const empty = (empty1 - empty0).toFixed(3);
  const args = (args1 - args0).toFixed(3);
  log(all, empty, args);

  if (useFastTick) {
    setTimeout(tick, 3);
  } else {
    setTimeout(() => requestAnimationFrame(tick), 1000 * interval);
  }
}

if (start) requestAnimationFrame(tick);



// log results to console
function log(all, empty, args) {
  console.group(`${all}ms`);
  console.log(`Empty: ${empty}ms`);
  console.log(`Arrgs: ${args}ms`);
  console.groupEnd();
}
```